# Paypal IPN Sandbox always return INVALID (WITH DEBUG)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement PayPal IPN but always returns INVALID. I know it's a recurring question and I've looked at similar questions, but I can not fix it.
I created an account on Paypal developer and the sandbox. I set up the account on a sandbox with IPN url.
I test the IPN simulator, get the message green "IPN was sent and the handshake was verified."

My code is the same as giving Paypal example, changing the url to point to the sandbox.

```
<?php

define("DEBUG", 1);
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}

foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // default: 1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // default: 2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------ START HTTP REQUEST OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------ END HTTP REQUEST OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(PHP_EOL ."*". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------ START RESPONSE OF VALIDATION REQUEST -------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------- END RESPONSE OF VALIDATION REQUEST -------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------- START VERIFIED IPN-------------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------- END VERIFIED IPN-------------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------ START INVALID IPN ----------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        error_log(PHP_EOL . "------------------------- END INVALID IPN ----------------------------\n" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}

?>
```

And this is the debug file. The data receipt and then sending are the same. I checked this with diffchecker.

```
--- START HTTP REQUEST OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---
[2016-05-31 11:50 UTC] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 930
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Tue+May+31+2016+13%3A50%3A22+GMT+0200+%28Hora+de+verano+romance%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=705782812&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AnTtKanWvA9fOSykMNVIDFCr8B6oAIL.gR5ZR2RjDD.y8fHCYDoudx6e
--- END HTTP REQUEST OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---

--- START RESPONSE OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---
[2016-05-31 11:50 UTC] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 May 2016 11:50:28 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=tiFAjXzjRap-cueIy6IvOIuyXEDeOqGj2EOZ4kGxnAcHI6wUU6Jt_CbHdK5imoAsJCKRirDu-jdw_IrfdkaJa77vQUvlkG6tZnaedRck1D8pqjwX3yVn7iaA-95NMS4yvpv4sIhWjFbeo7qr1dJVVoIB5Pi6fKMw1r8-ipWfhL10rl4yPYXrRMozluR_GfE6axFxKGZuuQa3oJrWNHAozFy4AgqbvRdT4tQdF2xmlxbjElokDVQQbG9z2K4aNECvAoVMl8TF1ilGIebFsQGhDD_uLXhrGxCaCiBBvMrUHagnlbXmrqeKomEl5zADjdrMHuvpnb4SpsDKGo-bjbgNsKNveM6j3Y1Mdn8TQlXjv4M5S5Ei19S1ks_H3AcHWLygzcsy5i5e7YJvor_PKyrnFepc3o9ILnj6Xx0izzZgf5vrQxkiddGZESmeJUe; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Fri, 29-May-2026 11:50:29 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Thu, 31-May-2018 11:50:29 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.108.11.1464695428758058; path=/; expires=Thu, 24-May-46 11:50:28 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: eaa609cbb480c
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D2222607703%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc; Expires=Tue, 31 May 2016 12:20:29 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

INVALID
--- END RESPONSE OF VALIDATION REQUEST ---

--- START INVALID IPN ---
[2016-05-31 11:50 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Tue+May+31+2016+13%3A50%3A22+GMT+0200+%28Hora+de+verano+romance%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=705782812&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AnTtKanWvA9fOSykMNVIDFCr8B6oAIL.gR5ZR2RjDD.y8fHCYDoudx6e
--- END INVALID IPN ---
```

Where is the problem? I can't find it.

EDIT * NEW TEST CODE

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$pre = "cmd=_notify-validate";
$req = $pre."&".$raw_post_data;
```

---

```
RECEIVED
payment_type=instant&payment_date=Wed%20Jun%2001%202016%2017%3A23%3A30%20GMT+0200%20%28Hora%20de%20verano%20romance%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=218898678&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A2H6KSDfssM5U2ik4231sae5BneW

SENT
cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Wed%20Jun%2001%202016%2017%3A23%3A30%20GMT+0200%20%28Hora%20de%20verano%20romance%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=218898678&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A2H6KSDfssM5U2ik4231sae5BneW

RESULT = INVALID
```

---

```
RECEIVED
payment_type=instant&payment_date=Any%20character%20except%20%28more%29%20-%20123&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=218898678&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A05enR9AkCnaKLwF3GcNFhj87aOl

SENT
cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Any%20character%20except%20%28more%29%20-%20123&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer@paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller@paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross_1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=218898678&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A05enR9AkCnaKLwF3GcNFhj87aOl

RESULT = VERIFIED
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the PHP sample code that PayPal provides is absolute garbage from beginning to end and should not be used. For instance, the code you have is re-inventing the `$_POST` superglobal for no real reason. It's also ignoring the existence of `parse_str()` and `http_build_query()` functions for safely processing url-encoded data. It's just a huge mess and I had a much easier time just re-writing it from scratch.

Comment: In fact the query-building may be the issue. I'm pretty sure the timezone should be `GMT+0200`, but since you haven't encoded the `+` correctly, PayPal is reading it as `GMT 0200`, which doesn't match and therefore would cause an `INVALID` reply.

Comment: I've been testing and indeed the error is in the field "payment_date".
I tried it with a simpler code on the grounds that I have to return the same data
I receive but adding the prefix cmd=_notify-validate& .

In the IPN Simulator I have done several tests, and returns VERIFIED me on all occasions, except where the character "+" appears.
Paypal always sends this field with the "+" character included by default, as do I treat this field or return to return to paypal verified me?

Comment: Personally I just have something akin to `$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate&'.http_build_query($_POST);` working just fine.

Comment: Just try your work but still returns invalid. I have noticed that has changed the way of coding, now the blanks change them by '+'. Any more ideas? Ex: cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Wed+Jun+01+2016+17%3A41%3A55+GMT+0200+%28Hora+de+verano+romance%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&...

Comment: Any idea that does not encode either the date even using http_build_query ($ _ POST) ?. The problem is with the character '+'.